# ews managed api download location?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, exchangewebservices

I cannot find a download location for the ews api. I need it to work in Visual c# express 2010 but i can only find it on [github](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/blob/master/README.md) however this then points me to [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices/) which as far as I can tell does not work with Vc# 2010. Does anyone know where I can download the dll that works with 2010 visual studio? or can anyone tell me what I am missing from the links provided?

Answer (score 0):

The last released version is 2.2 which you can download from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42951 . If you have Visual Studio though you can clone the GitHub Repo and then build your own version.

Cheers
Glen